# Check if file is *child of folder

Tags: c, directory, filenames

I have a directory name and a subpath, e.g. `"./files"` and `"/example.txt"`. While the directory can be arbitrarily placed in the filesystem, I need to make sure that directory+subpath (`"./files/example.txt"`) actually is inside the given directory. So this example would be valid, while subpath `"/../example.txt"` would be invalid because it is neither a child of the directory, nor a grandchild, etc. Soft-links leading outside of the directory are allowed.

How should I perform this test in C?

- My first guess was to use `realpath(directory_subpath)` and comparing the start of the result with `realpath(directory)`, but after reading about the problems with `PATH_MAX` I'm a bit unsure about that, and this is also likely to cause problems with soft-links.
- My second idea is simply checking if the subpath starts with `/../` and if is, resulting in invalid. If `/../` exists anywhere else in the subpath, the directory name before that will be removed (from left-to-right, repeating this until the path turns out to be invalid or the end of the path name is reached).

The `subpath` might be given with malicious intent, so I want to be really, really sure about this. Is my second approach safe? Is there a different, better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach is safe if you check for `/..` (without trailing slash).

I would just forbid `..` in the subpath: the cases when `..` is really necessary and is not malicious are rather rare.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Why do I have to omit the trailing slash? For the case of subpath being `"/.."` only or does it have another reason? What about Windows, if I replace `/` with `\`, do the same rules apply about `..` or is there something else to consider?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of the subpath=`"/.."` case. And yes, in Windows it's pretty much the same although you may discover that some names like 'NUL' or 'AUX' cannot be used for files.